# DCV gateway healtcheck not working, connection reset by peer

Tags: docker, health-check

I am deploying a DCV Gateway docker container in a Swarm cluster. I really need to have a healthcheck working for this container. In the case of DCV gateway, the healthcheck should be extremely easy to setup:

```
[health-check]
bind-addr = "0.0.0.0"
port = 8989
```

The problem is that the healtcheck continuosly fail. I tried to call the healtcheck API with curl and wget, and I get the same error:

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

--2024-02-02 13:36:03--  http://localhost:8989/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1, ::1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8989... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.
```

What am I doing wrong?